# Python => AutoML: XGBoost is not available; skipping it

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost, h2o, automl

I am getting this warning when running h2o AutoML. I have version 3.32.1.2 installed, and running it on python 3.8.

```
AutoML progress: |
11:30:52.773: AutoML: XGBoost is not available; skipping it.
```

CODE:

```
import h2o
h2o.init()

h2o_df = h2o.H2OFrame(df)

train, test = h2o_df.split_frame(ratios=[.75])

# Identify predictors and response
x = train.columns
y = "TERM_DEPOSIT"
x.remove(y)

from h2o.automl import H2OAutoML

aml = H2OAutoML(max_runtime_secs=600,
                #exclude_algos=['DeepLearning'],
                seed=1,
                #stopping_metric='logloss',
                #sort_metric='logloss',
                balance_classes=False,
                project_name='Completed'
)
%time aml.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train)
```

Comment: Hi Leo, you can also try MLJAR AutoML, it is an open-source python package, it has xgboost, lightgbm and catboost algorithms (from the GBM family) https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised

Answer (score 3):

XGBoost is not supported on Windows, see the [limitations](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/xgboost.html#limitations) in the H2O documentation.

If you are not using Windows and you didn't find another reason in the documentation mentioned above, you can try to reinstall h2o, e.g.,

```
pip install --force-reinstall https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-zipf/2/Python/h2o-3.32.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer to this warning. I am running a windows machine.

https://twitter.com/ledell/status/1148512129659625472?lang=en

> If you're on Windows, XGBoost is not supported  so the parts of the tutorial that use XGBoost can be replaced by `h2o.gbm()`. The AutoML process will also exclude XGBoost models.